# Hide user input in PhantomJS / CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a CasperJS test suite in which I have to fill a login form with user name and password. Since I don't want to put the password into the code I did something like this:

```
system.stdout.writeLine("Please enter password:");
var password = system.stdin.readLine();
this.fill('form:first-of-type',{
    'username': user,
    'password': password
},true);
```

This works, but it leaves the password on the console where anyone can read it. Is there a way to hide the actual input from view, or display ******** in its place?

Or is there perhaps another approach to the problem that I have missed?

Edit: I tried using `execFile`, but it doesn't do anything when I try to run `read`, it just returns like nothing ever happened. Other external programs work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a crude workaround:

```
system.stdout.write("Please enter password:");
var password = system.stdin.readLine();
system.stdout.write("\033[1APlease enter password:                      \n");
```

will move the cursor up one line and then print over the password. The problem remains, that it only hides the password **after** it has been entered. If anyone is watching you type, that won't help much. At least it won't be visible on the console later on.